# Can graalvm guest languages use 3rd party library?

Tags: java, graalvm

I am writing some java code that runs on graalvm 
I want it to execute an python script 
  The python script use an 3rd party libray  
When I run my java code it come out an ModuleNotFoundError Exception

```
// java code
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try(Context ctx = Context.newBuilder().allowAllAccess(true).build()){
        Path scriptPath = Paths.get("/home/hyc/Desktop/py_script.py");
        String script = Files.readString(scriptPath);
        Value value = ctx.eval("python", script);
    }
}

// py_script.py
import requests                                                                                                        
url = 'http://www.google.com/'
strhtml = requests.get(url)        
print(strhtml.text)
```

source code link: https://github.com/huangdaren1997/polyglotDemo

**is graalvm guest languages can use 3rd party library ? And how to do it ?**

OS: Manjaro 20.2 Nibia
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.9.11-3-MANJARO
Python: Python 3.8.6
openjdk 11 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 20.3.0

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add what operating system you have, and the command you are using to invoke `java`

Comment: I think the packages need to be installed the same way as for any python implementation. For graalpython, this doc can maybe help: https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/python/Packages/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to install the package, which I assume you've done, but just to make this answer complete:

```
graalpython -m ginstall install requests
```

Then you need to configure GraalPython to import [the site module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html). This is done by default if you run GraalPython via the executable, but not when you embed GraalPython in Java:

```
Context.newBuilder().option("python.ForceImportSite", "true")...
```

Note that this set-up will depend on the required packages being installed in the site library. Bit cleaner solution may be to use the [`venv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) that GraalPython also supports:

```
graalpython -m venv /path/to/you/new/venv/directory
```

then install what you need

```
/path/to/you/new/venv/directory/bin/graalpython -m ginstall install ...
```

and then additionally pass this option to GraalPython:

```
.option("python.SysPrefix", "/path/to/you/new/venv/directory")
```

Edit: there is now an article about this whole use-case: https://medium.com/graalvm/supercharge-your-java-apps-with-python-ec5d30634d18

Comment: Note that configuring `python.ForceImportSite` requires `.allowExperimentalOptions(true)` to be set on the builder as well